# Alternative to iTunes for syncing with iPhone?

Tags: apple

iTunes software is needed to sync Musics and Videos with Apple iPhone which I have.

Does Ubuntu have something for alternative iTunes?

Mobile Ubuntu has not been published yet in Seoul, Republic of Korea where I live.

Comment: The duplicate has an answer for iPod which is different from iPhone. Not MP3s but MP4s and M4As.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amarok and, if I recall correctly, Banshee, have some level of support for syncing music with iPhone. Note that I haven't tried Amarok, and it's been a long time since I used Banshee, so I can't comment on the functionality or stability.